# Get list of marks inside Vimscript

Tags: vimscript, mark

some time ago, I wrote a small plugin in vimscript that was using builtin function `getmarklist`. Recently I reinstalled Vim and was surprissed that this plugin no longer worked because Vim couldn't find `getmarklist`. I don't know if this function was removed or this has something to do with build architecture. My old Vim was 64bit, this one is 32bit.
So my question is, is there some other way to get list of all marks in vimscript?

Thanks

Comment: Check `:version`? My vim (8.2.1800) has this function

Comment: I don't have it in my build from May of this year. So it was there, removed some time ago, and added back very recently? I don't recall this function at all. Worst case I suppose you could `redir` the `:marks` command...if it contains what  you need.

Comment: @BLayer Added in 8.2.0861 on 31st May. Still not present in Neovim.

Comment: @Matt Looks like I pulled source about three weeks too early. :)

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of marks in vimscript just use the following command:

```
:marks
```

I would also recommend the plugin called: [vim-signature](https://github.com/kshenoy/vim-signature).  This plugin will automatically display marks in vim.  Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can write the output of `:marks` to a string called `str` like this:

```
fun! Marklist() abort
  redir => str
  :silent marks
  redir END
  return str
endfun
```