# How do I convert a file mark to a string?

Tags: vimscript, mark, string-manipulation

If I for example create a mark inside the file `~/.vimrc` with `mV`.

How do I convert the mark `'V` to the path of the file the mark is in?

When I type `:marks` I can see a list of marks and the corresponding file paths.

Perhaps I can put this list into a string somehow in order to retrieve the file path, but how?

I want to make a function that jumps to the file of the mark at the position where my cursor was last and not at the mark position.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to store the :marks output into a string without using the getmarklist() function

```
fun! Marklist() abort
  redir => str
  :silent marks
  redir END
  " do something with str here ...
endfun
```

But in the end i used a different way to achieve my goal:

```
let fileMarkKeys = [ "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z" ]
let fileMarkKeysLen = len(fileMarkKeys)
let i = 0 
while i < fileMarkKeysLen
    exe "nnoremap <leader>'" . fileMarkKeys[i] . " '" . fileMarkKeys[i] . "g`\""
    let i += 1
endwhile
```

I put the above code into my `.vimrc`
Now when i use a capital mark like `<leader>'V` it will jump to my vimrc file in the buffer and automatically go the latest cursor position. (and not to the mark position)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look at "`:help getmarklist()`" which can give you a list of global marks or, if you prefer, local marks of a specified buffer.

However, this sounds like you just want to restore the cursor when you enter a buffer. Have you looked at "`:help restore-cursor`"?  It has this autocmd as an example:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *
  \ if line("'\"") >= 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") && &ft !~# 'commit'
  \ |   exe "normal! g`\""
  \ | endif
```

This just causes your cursor to jump to the last known position within a file whenever you open it for the first time in a Vim session.

Comment: sadly my vim doesn't have the function `getmarklist()`, i will take a look at restore-cursor, found related answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28088/get-list-of-marks-inside-vimscript i will do more research